# How do I place a button on the right side of this bootstrap base nav?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here is my code derived from this topic: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#base-nav (Boostrap v4.0). How do I place the "TRY NOW" button on the right side of this bootstrap base navigation?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="nav">
  <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Overview</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resources</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#" role="button">TRY NOW</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you really using Bootstrap 4.0? That's very old. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="nav align-items-center">
  <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Overview</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resources</a>
  <div class="ml-auto">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " href="#" role="button">TRY NOW</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vertical alignment is not perfect, sorry. The button vertical position is higher than the text links one.

Comment: Also put `align-items-center` on the `nav` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **ml-auto** to "TRY NOW" button

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="nav">
  <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Overview</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resources</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-auto" href="#" role="button">TRY NOW</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The vertical alignment is bad, sorry